# Deploy ASPNET core app to IIS on a server : 0xc0000409 exception with ucrtbase.dll module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core, web-deployment

Some months ago I started to develop an ASP.NET Core (v2.2.5) application on visual studio, it works perfectly on my pc.
Now I want to install this application on an IIS server on a server, so I published it from VS, but when I launch the site, I have this popup that appears :
[Visual studio debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzxuf.png)

and in the Event Viewer I get this error:

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
>   Faulting module name: ucrtbase.DLL, version: 10.0.14393.2630, time stamp: 0x5bbec6c9
>   Exception code: 0xc0000409
>   Fault offset: 0x000000000006d3d8
>   Faulting process id: 0xcec
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d51d0e16ee383d
>   Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase.DLL
>   Report Id: 56e081de-8901-11e9-8113-00155d013e00
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

and this information about the error:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: BEX64 Response: Not available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: w3wp.exe P2: 8.5.9600.16384 P3: 5215df96 P4:
>   ucrtbase.DLL P5: 10.0.14393.2630 P6: 5bbec6c9 P7: 000000000006d3d8 P8:
>   c0000409 P9: 0000000000000005 P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> These files may be available here:
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   56e081de-8901-11e9-8113-00155d013e00 Report Status: 0 Hashed bucket:

I think it's similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623972/asp-net-core-2-2-release-produces-an-error-and-stops-w3wp) but the solutions proposed didn't worked for me.
Could you help me with that?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: And if you go in the folder where your application is published and run "dotnet run" in a command line, is it working well? we would need to know if the application is running on his own to make sure the issue is coming from the fact that it is hosted on IIS.

Comment: I just did it and i get an error message about Telerik :
error NU1102: Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core.Trial with version (>= 2018.3.1017)
So I think I have to install telerik or some dependencies on the server, I'll take a look at this, already thanks for this !

Comment: Actually it was an old reference to the trial package of telerik on my classes project, I juste removed it and... it's working now! Thanks for your help !!

Comment: all good then, just a missing reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a reference to an old (and non longer existing) packet on another project, so when I removed it, the website worked